# Is it possible to nock an external service call inside a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

I'm trying to test a rest api which calls an external service.

### server.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const redirectUrl = require('../utils/redirection')

let baseUrl = 'myUrl';
let externalUrl = 'externalUrl';

router.get('/redirect', async (req, res) => {

  const { productName } = req.query;

  baseUrl = baseUrl + '/' + productName;
  externalUrl = externalUrl + '/' + productName;
  await redirectUrl(res)(timeOut, externalUrl, baseUrl)

})
app.use(router);

app.listen(3000);
```

### utils/redirection.js:

```js
edirectUrl = res => (timeOut, url, redirectUrl) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let cleared = false;

const timer = setTimeout(() => {
  cleared = true;
  return resolve(res.redirect(302, redirectUrl));
}, timeout);


return fetch(url)
  .then(
    response => {
      if (!cleared) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        const {location} = response.headers;
        return resolve(res.redirect(302, location));
      }

      return null;
    })
  .catch(err => {
    if (!cleared) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      return reject(err);
    }
  });


 });
}
```

### test.js:

```js
const requrest = require('request');
const chai = require('chai');
const server = require('../server/server');
const { expect } = chai;
describe('My test', () => {
  it('should redirects to the suitable page', () => {

   nock('url/to/external/service')
   .get('/${productName}')
   .reply(302, {
      headers: {
        location: 'this the page location'
   }})       

    const { status, headers } = request(app).get('/redirect')
    expect(status).to.equal(302);
    expect(headers.location).to.not.equal(0);

  })
})
```

When I execute the test, the `request` launches the API call. Then the `redirectUrl` was called inside. But `nock` does not intercept the request and the server call the external api. Does nock could intercept a depth HTTP request? or I missed something in my code? Does any suggestion please to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a running example it's hard to tell what is going wrong. But I can tell there's a few things you can change here (I was also struggling with Nock today).

First, since you're dealing with redirects, take a look at this comment. This worked for me: https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/147#issuecomment-71433752

Second, pay attention: the syntax to specify headers is wrong, this is the correct one:

```
nock('url/to/external/service')
   .get('/${productName}')
   .reply(302, 'whatever you want', {
      location: 'http://the.other.page.location'
   })
```

Third: split your **server.js** file into two: **server.j**s and **app.js**.

**app.js**

```
const app = express()
...
module.exports = app
```

**server.js**

```
const app = require('./path/to/app.js')
...
app.listen(3000)
```

This way you can import your **app.js** into your test suite without the listen part, which will avoid problems with network ports when new tests are run.

Let me know if this helped...